# Thread.sleep inside infinite while loop in lambda doesn't require 'catch (InterruptedException)' - why not?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, compilation, functional-interface

My question is about `InterruptedException`, which is thrown from the `Thread.sleep` method. While working with `ExecutorService` I noticed some weird behaviour that I don't understand; here is what I mean:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while(true)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    });
```

With this code, the compiler doesn't give me any error or message that `InterruptedException` from `Thread.sleep` should be caught. But when I am trying to change the loop condition and replace "true" with some variable like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while(tasksObserving)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    });
```

The compiler constantly complains that `InterruptedException` has to be handled. Can someone explain to me why this happens, and why if the condition is set to true the compiler ignores the InterruptedException?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on that `DO SOMETHING`? It is crucial to give a precise answer. For example, if `DO SOMETHING` is empty, the first code block with `while (true)` will just not compile. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad: the first code block actually compiles (I was misled by my IDE), and no additional information from the OP is needed. I've totally rewritten my answer after the new research.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The reason for this, is that these invocations are in fact, invocations to two different overloaded methods available in `ExecutorService`; each of these methods taking a single argument of different types:

> 1. `<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task);`
>    2.     `Future<?> submit(Runnable task);`

Then what happens is that the compiler is converting the lambda in the first case of your problem into a `Callable<?>` functional interface (invoking the first overloaded method); and in the second case of your problem converts the lambda into a `Runnable` functional interface (invoking therefore the second overloaded method), requiring because of this to handle the `Exception` thrown; but not in the previous case using the `Callable`.

Although both functional interfaces don't take any arguments, `Callable<?>` **returns a value**:

> 1. Callable<?>: `V call() throws Exception;`
>    2. Runnable: `public abstract void run();`

If we switch to examples that trim the code to the relevant pieces (to easily investigate just the curious bits) then we can write, equivalently to the original examples:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    // LAMBDA COMPILED INTO A 'Callable<?>'
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while (true)
            throw new Exception();
    });
    
    // LAMBDA COMPILED INTO A 'Runnable': EXCEPTIONS MUST BE HANDLED BY LAMBDA ITSELF!
    executor.submit(() -> {
        boolean value = true;
        while (value)
            throw new Exception();
    });
```

With these examples, it may be easier to observe that the reason why the first one is converted to a `Callable<?>`, while the second one is converted to a `Runnable` is because of *compiler inferences*.

In both cases, the lambda bodies are [void-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2), since every return statement in the block has the form `return;`.

Now, in the first case, the compiler does the following:

1. Detects that all execution paths in the lambda declare throwing [checked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) (from now on we will refer as *'exception'*, implying only *'checked exceptions'*). This includes the invocation of any method declaring throwing exceptions and the explicit invocation to `throw new <CHECKED_EXCEPTION>()`.
2. Concludes correctly that the **WHOLE** body of the lambda is equivalent to a block of code declaring throwing exceptions; which of course **MUST** be either: handled or re-thrown.
3. Since the lambda is not handling the exception, then the compiler defaults to assume that these exception(s) must be re-thrown.
4. Safely infers that this lambda must match a functional interface cannot `complete normally` and therefore is [value-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2).
5. Since `Callable<?>` and `Runnable` are potential matches for this lambda, the compiler selects the most specific match (to cover all scenarios); which is the `Callable<?>`, converting the lambda into an instance of it and creating an invocation reference to the `submit(Callable<?>)` overloaded method.

While, in the second case, the compiler does the following:

1. Detects that there may be execution paths in the lambda that **DO NOT** declare throwing exceptions (depending on *to-be-evaluated logic*).
2. Since not all execution paths declare throwing exceptions, the compiler concludes that the body of the lambda is **NOT NECESSARILY** equivalent to a block of code declaring throwing exceptions - compiler doesn't care/pay attention if some portions of the code do declare that they may, only if the whole body does or not.
3. Safely infers that the lambda is not [value-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2); since it **MAY** `complete normally`.
4. Selects `Runnable` (as it is the only available *fitting* functional interface for the lambda to be converted into) and creates an invocation reference to the `submit(Runnable)` overloaded method. All this coming at the price of delegating to the user, the responsibility of handling any `Exception`s thrown wherever they **MAY** occur within portions of the lambda body.

This was a great question - I had a lot of fun chasing it down, thanks!

Comment: I think you have reversed Runnable and Callable.  The first code block does not require catching of InterruptedException because the lambda is interpreted as a Callable.  Also, I do not understand your explanation of why one lambda is interpreted as a Callable but not the other one;  both are equally likely to throw InterruptedException.

Comment: You are right, I accidentally swapped them relative to the question when working them out the more focus examples. Regarding interpretation to Callable, it is a compiler *optimization*, I'll elaborate in the answer.

Comment: @MarcoR. flawless answer! Kudos!

Comment: @MarcoR. This answer is great and informative!  One question though (as a reader of this question purely for knowledge's sake): Why can we safely and without loss of generality convert Thread.sleep (in the OP) to throw new Exception (in your answer)?  As far as I'm aware, Thread.sleep does not always throw an exception, and thus it occurs to me that in either case the compiler should infer that both cases may or may not throw an exception based on system state at runtime.  What am I missing?

Comment: That's a good question, it was just poor choice of words on my part; it is not as much as the body of the lambda *may/will throw exception(s)* as it is that the body of the lambda is equivalent to *declaring throwing exception(s)* (which must be catch or rethrown). I edited the answer to be more precise around this potential confusion. Thanks for the heads up, lmk if it still seems unclear or if you have any other question.

Comment: @MarcoR. I'm still somewhat unclear.  Would it be correct to say the following?  Since in the first case, in the original post, we have a while true (which we always enter), and the body of the while true throws an exception (in the sense that it consists of one or more method calls whose method signatures have throws clauses, not in the sense that they always throw an exception in all cases), then the compiler infers that the matching overloaded interface for the entire lambda must also throw an exception; in the latter case because the loop is a while condition, then it is not guaranteed...

Comment: ... that every control flow of that lambda contains any method call whose method signature contains a throws clause, and therefore it fits to the overloaded interface which does not throw an exception by default.  This would be kind of a very strange and complex compiler optimization, I suppose, which is why I find it somewhat hard to believe, although it would certainly not be the strangest thing I've heard of Java doing.

Comment: @Ertai87 The compiler doesn't infer runtime behavior, so it's not as much as inferring what the code is **going** to do, as much as what it **declares of potentially** doing. In the `Callable` case, the lambda body can be correctly interpreted of **declaring as a whole** capable of throwing exceptions (which must be handled of declare rethrowing). In the `Runnable` case, the lambda body **CANNOT** be generalized as **declaring as a whole** of throwing exceptions - compiler doesn't care/pay attention if some portions of the code do declare that they may, only if the whole body does or not.

Comment: Sorry guys, but `throws` clause has nothing to do with the functional interface selection. What matters here is whether any `return` is reachable from the point of view of the compiler, and which flavor it is (with or without an operand). See my answer for details.

Comment: @Roman - I just added a section in the answer to address your incorrect 'corrections'. I **DID** answer the question correctly as it was asked - don't change the question to invalidate my answer.

Comment: @MarcoR.I'm flattered by the amount of the attention, but let's stay on the topic. I apologize if I hurt your feelings, I just wanted (and still want) to solve the mistery. Could you please provide me (and the rest of us) with a link to Java Language Specification where it says that `throws` declaration has anything to do with method selection during compile time?

Answer (score 3):

## Briefly

`ExecutorService` has both `submit(Callable)` and `submit(Runnable)` methods.

1. In the first case (with the `while (true)`), both `submit(Callable)` and `submit(Runnable)` match, so the compiler has to choose between them

   - `submit(Callable)` is chosen over `submit(Runnable)` because `Callable` is *more specific* than `Runnable`
   - `Callable` has `throws Exception` in `call()`, so it is not necessary to catch an exception inside it
2. In the second case (with the `while (tasksObserving)`) only `submit(Runnable)` match, so the compiler chooses it

   - `Runnable` has no `throws` declaration on its `run()` method, so it is a compilation error to not catch the exception inside the `run()` method.

## The full story

Java Language Specification describes how the method is chosen during program compilation in [$15.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) :

1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods ([$15.12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)) which is done in 3 phases for strict, loose and variable arity invocation
2. Choose the Most Specific Method ([$15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) from the methods found on the first step.

Let's analyze the situation with 2 `submit()` methods in two code snippets provided by the OP:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while(true)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    });
```

and

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while(tasksObserving)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    });
```

(where `tasksObserving` is not a final variable).

### Identify Potentially Applicable Methods

First, the compiler has to identify the *potentially applicable methods*: $15.12.2.1

> If the member is a fixed arity method with arity n, the arity of the method invocation is equal to n, and for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), the i'th argument of the method invocation is *potentially compatible*, as defined below, with the type of the i'th parameter of the method.

and a bit further in the same section

> An expression is *potentially compatible* with a target type according to the following rules:
>
> A lambda expression (§15.27) is potentially compatible with a functional interface type (§9.8) if all of the following are true:
>
> The arity of the target type's function type is the same as the arity of the lambda expression.
>
> If the target type's function type has a void return, then the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block (§15.27.2).
>
> If the target type's function type has a (non-void) return type, then the lambda body is either an expression or a value-compatible block (§15.27.2).

Let's note that in both cases, the lambda is a block lambda.

Let's also note that `Runnable` has `void` return type, so to be *potentially compatible* with `Runnable`, a block lambda must be *void-compatible block*. At the same time, `Callable` has a non-void return type, so to be *potentially comtatible* with `Callable`, a block lambda must be *value-compatible block*.

$15.27.2 defines what a *void-compatible-block* and *value-compatible-block* are.

> A block lambda body is void-compatible if every return statement in the block has the form `return;`.
>
> A block lambda body is value-compatible if it cannot complete normally (§14.21) and every return statement in the block has the form `return Expression;`.

Let's look at $14.21, paragraph about `while` loop:

> A while statement can complete normally iff at least one of the following is true:
>
> The while statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
>
> There is a reachable break statement that exits the while statement.

In borh cases, lambdas are actually block lambdas.

In the first case, as it can be seen, there is a `while` loop with a constant expression with value `true` (without `break` statements), so it cannot complete normallly (by $14.21); also it has no return statements, hence the first lambda is *value-compatible*.

At the same time, there are no `return` statements at all, so it is also *void-compatible*. So, in the end, **in the first case, the lambda is both void- and value-compatible**.

In the second case, the `while` loop *can complete normally* from the point of view of the compiler (because the loop expression is not a constant expression anymore), so the lambda in its entirety *can complete normally*, so it is **not** a *value-compatible block*. But **it is still a void-compatible block** because it contains no `return` statements.

The intermediate result is that in the first case the lambda is both a *void-compatible block* and a *value-compatible block*; in the second case it is **only** a *void-compatible block*.

Recalling what we noted earlier, this means that in the first case, the lambda will be *potentially compatible* both with `Callable` and `Runnable`; in the second case, the lambda will only be *potentially compatible* with `Runnable`.

### Choose the Most Specific Method

For the first case, the compiler has to choose between the two methods because both are *potentially applicable*. It does so using the procedure called 'Choose the Most Specific Method' and described in $15.12.2.5. Here is an excerpt:

> A functional interface type S is more specific than a functional interface type T for an expression e if T is not a subtype of S and one of the following is true (where U1 ... Uk and R1 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of the capture of S, and V1 ... Vk and R2 are the parameter types and return type of the function type of T):
>
> If e is an explicitly typed lambda expression (§15.27.1), then one of the following is true:
>
> R2 is void.

First of all,

> A lambda expression with zero parameters is explicitly typed.

Also, neither of `Runnable` and `Callable` is a subclass of one another, and `Runnable` return type is `void`, so we have a match: **`Callable` is more specific than `Runnable`**. This means that between `submit(Callable)` and `submit(Runnable)` in the first case the method with `Callable` will be chosen.

As for the second case, there we only have one *potentially applicable* method, `submit(Runnable)`, so it is chosen.

### So why does the change surface?

So, in the end, we can see that in these cases different methods are chosen by the compiler. In the first case, the lambda is inferred to be a `Callable` which has `throws Exception` on its `call()` method, so that `sleep()` call compiles. In the second case, it's `Runnable` which `run()` does not declare any throwable exceptions, so the compiler complains about an exception not being caught.