# Same erasure on for subclass that maps parent method to a different class

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, design-patterns, collections

I am attempting to refactor a DAO to make it a bit more usable in our code base. We currently have a parameterized AbstractDao that takes in three types:

1. The database table
2. The database pojo
3. A different mapped pojo representation of 2)

So it ends up looking like:

```
public class AbstractDao<T extends DatabaseTable, R extends DatabaseRecord, M> {
  public AbstractDao(Connection connection, Mapper<R,M> mapper) {
  //save connection and mapper to protected variables
}
public List<M> insert(List<M> records) {
 connection.insertBulk(
   StreamEx.of(records).map(mapper::map).toList()
 );
 }
}
```

However, this doesn't work on the classic DAO case where we are dealing only with the pojo and the table.

However, there is a common functionality here that can be abstracted into a more basic AbstractDao that is useful across projects. Something like:

```
AbstractDao<T extends DatabaseTable, R extends Record>
```

which has a subclass

```
AbstractMappedDao<T extends DatabaseTable, R extends Record, M> extends AbstractDao<T, R>
```

The Abstract has a method like:

```
public List<R> insert(List<R> records) {
  connection.insertBulk(records);
}
```

and the Mapped should have a method like:

```
public List<M> insert(List<M> records) {
  super.insert(StreamEx.of(records).map(mapper::map).toList());
}
```

However, this gives a "same erasure" issue because insert takes in a List of generics.

I have tried abstracting it out into an interface:

```
public interface Dao<T> {
  public List<T> insert(List<T> records);
}
```

And making Abstract implement Dao and Mapped implement Dao, but again, same issue.

So my question is how to best approach this problem? This works as expected if I change map's signature to something like:

```
insertMapped(List<M> mapped);
```

But I would prefer to keep the contract the same.

Thanks for the help. Looking forward to the discussion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes down to *composing behavior* it is always best to either use composition over inheritance, and this is actually your case. The `mapper` does not *augment* behavior already existing in your `Dao` as much as *adds* behavior, an extra layer of indirection in it; which is not necessarily a concern of the `Dao`, like an [*aspect/cross cutting concern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

So, my recommendation is to create a single `AbstractDao` class with the ability to compose `mappers` (you can have just one as you wanted; but with composition is easy to allow a single `Dao` object to support multiple mappers):

```
        private Map<Class, Function> mappers;
        
        public <M> void registerMapper(Class<M> mappingClass, Function<M, R> mapper) {
            mappers.put(mappingClass, mapper);
        }
```

Then create an `insert` method that allows for handling the *pre-transformation* of the records that do not extend `Record` using the `mappers` that it has registered, like this:

```
        public <M> List<M> insert(List<M> records) {
            if (records.isEmpty()) return records;
            M rec = records.get(0);
            
            List<? extends Record> actualRecords = (rec instanceof Record) ? 
                    (List<Record>)records : createMappedRecords(records, rec.getClass());
            
            connection.insertBulk(actualRecords);
            return records;
        }
```

This is cleaner, more robust and more extensible, since your `insert` can be made to entertain all sorts of concerns in a centralized manner with *composed concerns*. The full compiling code would look like something like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParentErasure {

    public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends DatabaseTable, R extends Record> {
        private Connection connection;
        private Map<Class, Function> mappers = new HashMap<>();
        
        public <M> void registerMapper(Class<M> mappingClass, Function<M, R> mapper) {
            mappers.put(mappingClass, mapper);
        }
        
        public <M> List<M> insert(List<M> records) {
            if (records.isEmpty()) return records;
            M rec = records.get(0);
            
            List<? extends Record> actualRecords = (rec instanceof Record) ? 
                    (List<Record>)records : createMappedRecords(records, rec.getClass());
            
            connection.insertBulk(actualRecords);
            return records;
        }

        private <M> List<R> createMappedRecords(List<M> records, Class<? extends Object> recordsClazz) {
            Function<M, R> mapper = mappers.get(recordsClazz);
            return records.stream()
                    .map(mapper::apply)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
    
    public interface Dao<T> {
        public List<T> insert(List<T> records);
    }
}

class Record {}
class DatabaseTable {}
class DatabaseRecord {}
class Connection {
    public void insertBulk(List<? extends Record> records) {}
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56195697)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think this is along the lines of what I was looking for. The whole "composure over inheritance" design principal is one that I'm looking forward to reading up on. Definitely points me in the right direction!

Comment: Here you are composing behavior like when you pass lambdas as arguments. Although with passing lambdas you need to be careful with some of its nuances such as the ones I described in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149752/thread-sleep-inside-infinite-while-loop-doesnt-throw-exception-why/56150419#56150419